# Laying tefillin in kiruv

Tags: tefilin, chabad, kiruv-outreach

From what I've seen, when groups like Chabbad get [otd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_the_derech) Jews to wear tefillin, they don't have them make birkot hatorah (or any of the birkot hashachar). Perhaps they're just relying on the Ashkenazi custom to do exactly this. Assuming they aren't, would kiruv be a reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: Please clarify (via an [edit] to the question) what you mean by "the Ashkenazi custom to do exactly this": do you mean the _Ashk'nazi_ custom to get Jews to wear _t'filin_ without saying blessings? It's very unclear to me.

Comment: @msh210 I think the shulchan Aruch says to make birkas hatorah before saying pesukim even for prayer purposes, and the rema says it's ok not to. Maybe that's what he means

Comment: You're missing the entire point of the Chabad Tefillin Campaign, at least in the eyes of Chabad, though your concerns are shared by many authorities and is one of the reasons for opposition to the Campaign.

Comment: Ummm... Chabbad are Ashkenazim. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Most of the tefillin guides that Chabad uses have Birchat HaTorah in them. I was looking online to try and find some of the guides, but wasn't successful.